# Как открыть новую вкладку после фетча с проверкой на пустую ссылку

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
async clicked(e) {
    const w = window.open('', '_blank');
    const response = await someFunction();
    w.location.href = response.link;
}
```

Как можно заимплементить здесь проверку на пустую ссылку перед открытием нового окна?

Comment: что такое "пустая ссылка" - пустая строка/undefined/null?

Comment: пустая строка , если она пустая тогда не открывать новую табу

Comment: тогда так примерно https://pastebin.com/6hukJk1F

Comment: если так , тогда браузер блокирует  popup

Comment: `window.open` не блокируется только тогда, когда он вызывается действием пользователя, у меня в такой схеме работает https://jsfiddle.net/y4n2ruje/

Comment: @nörbörnën не просто действием пользователя, а именно кликом пользователя.

Comment: @nörbörnën ваш пример с фейк фетчом работает , но если добавить реальные фетч , тогда браузер блокирует

Comment: @IvanOlkhoviy вот вам реальный fetch https://jsfiddle.net/L6cdnxoe/

Comment: @DiD спасибо за комментарий. прошу, добавь ссылку на документацию, где это прописано явно

Comment: @nörbörnën https://ibb.co/qFQV6Wb , firefox блокирует )

Comment: @IvanOlkhoviy https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events

Comment: @IvanOlkhoviy https://jsfiddle.net/9p8tsme7/

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо :)